# Why would the exists() function work, but not apply in a boolean statement?

Tags: r, debugging, exists

I have a quick function that simply returns a string variable indicating whether or not the inputted tree exists.

```
buildSpreadTotalDF = function(tree){
  if (exists(as.character(substitute(tree)))){
     ret = "The tree exists"
  }
  else{
     ret = "There tree does not exist"
  }
ret
}
```

It seems that even if I do

```
remove(tree)
```

and check that the object tree does not exist by doing

```
tree
Error: object 'tree' not found
```

and even check the boolean statement separately from the function

```
> exists(as.character(substitute(tree)))
[1] FALSE
```

if I run the function as

```
ret = buildSpreadTotalDF(tree)
```

I will get

```
ret
[1] "The tree exists"
```

which seems counter-intuitive. Why would it still enter the first loop of the function when clearly tree does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you named your function argument `tree` so `"tree"` will always exist within the function's scope. Instead, pick an argument name that you are unlikely to be using as a variable name, for example:

```
buildSpreadTotalDF = function(.argh){
   if (exists(as.character(substitute(.argh)))){
      ret = "The tree exists"
   } else{
      ret = "The tree does not exist"
   }
   ret
}

tree <- 1
buildSpreadTotalDF(tree)
# [1] "The tree exists"

remove(tree)
buildSpreadTotalDF(tree)
# "The tree does not exist"
```

Comment: Wow, I was losing hope. And I could not find results by a search for this specific case either!

Comment: Or use the `where` argument to `exists` to skip the function environment.

Answer (score 2):

Be precise about where to look for the variable - you want to look in the parent frame, the environment from which your function was called:

```
tree_exist <- function(var) {
  var_name <- as.character(substitute(var)) 
  if (exists(var_name, envir = parent.frame())){
    "The tree exists"
  }  else {
    "The tree does not exist"
  }
}
tree_exist(tree_exist)
tree_exist(var_name)
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying how to get the scoping right with ```parent.frame()```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `exists` will look in the local scope first (which is the global environment when you just call `exists(...)` outside your function but is inside your function when called from there. Since `tree` is the name of the parameter passed to your function, it always exists *inside* the function. What you probably want to do is to look for your variable in the global environment. You can do this for example by specifying the `where` parameter, in a slightly modified example from yours, like so:

```
buildSpreadTotalDF = function(treename){
    if (exists(treename, where = globalenv())){
        ret = "The tree exists"
    }
    else{
        ret = "There tree does not exist"
    }
    ret
}

tree1 <- 1
buildSpreadTotalDF("tree1") # exists
buildSpreadTotalDF("tree2") # does not exist
```

Correction: I think I was wrong about the default scope of `exists(...)`, see answer above for good advice on just fixing the problem by using an unlikely variable name and the answer below for details on how to get the scoping right.